# VK_API, python, не могу выполнить запрос SQL, вставить время в столбец

Tags: python, mysql, vkontakte-api

суть ошибки в том, что я не могу внести время в столбец SQL. Вот код:

```
def digger(user_id, current_time, digger_salary_time):
    try:
        digger_salary_time = check_time_digger(user_id)['digger_time']
        print(f"Значение: {digger_salary_time}, тип: {type(digger_salary_time)}")
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Опа! Произошла ошиба в использовании команды /копать! {e}")
    if digger_salary_time == current_time:
        return True
    else:
        time_getting_ore = int(time.time() + 30)
        gg = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_getting_ore)
        try:
            res = next_salary_digger(user_id, gg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Опа! Произошла ошибка в использовании команды /копать! {e}")
        else:
            return False
```

Вот запросы SQL

```
def next_salary_digger(user_id):
    time_getting_ore = int(time.time() + 30)
    gg = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_getting_ore)
    print(gg)
    connection = connect()
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            result = cursor.execute(f"update untitled set `digger_time` = {gg} where uid = {user_id}")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            return row
    finally:
        connection.close()

def check_time_digger(user_id):
    connection = connect()
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            result = cursor.execute(f"SELECT digger_time FROM untitled WHERE uid={user_id}")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if result == 1:
                return row
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Вот сама команда

```
             elif event.text.lower() == "копать":
                message = "⛏ Вы отправились в шахту за ценными ресурсами. \n\n  Подождите 30 секунд, чтобы получить заработную плату."
                writemsg(message)
                user_id = event.user_id
                next_salary_digger(user_id)
                current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H.%M.%S')
                digger_salary_time = check_time_digger(user_id)['digger_time']
                digger(user_id, current_time, digger_salary_time)
                result_digger = digger(user_id, current_time, digger_salary_time)
                if result_digger is True:
                    message = "Время закончилось"
                    writemsg(message)
                else:
                    message = "Время не закончилось, жди"
                    writemsg(message)
```

Comment: вы не сказали какая СУБД... И вообще при чем тут vk api?

Comment: Решил сам, все работает.